# c# Regex trouble

Tags: c#, regex

I'm having a bit of trouble with my regex.

```
String a = @"{target=}jump";
String b = "continue";
String c = "jump";
String d = @"{target=intro}jump";
String e = "prev";
String f = @"{target=}choice";
String g = @"{target=intro}choice";
String h = "choice";
String i = "previous";
String j = @"{target=intro}continue";
String k = "cont";
String l = @"{target=}continue";
Regex regex = new Regex(@"(^{target=(\w.*)}(choice|jump))|(^[^.]*(continue|previous))");
var a_res = regex.IsMatch(a);
var b_res = regex.IsMatch(b);
var c_res = regex.IsMatch(c);
var d_res = regex.IsMatch(d);
var e_res = regex.IsMatch(e);
var f_res = regex.IsMatch(f);
var g_res = regex.IsMatch(g);
var h_res = regex.IsMatch(h);
var i_res = regex.IsMatch(i);
var j_res = regex.IsMatch(j);
var k_res = regex.IsMatch(k);
var l_res = regex.IsMatch(l);
```

Basically what i need is to get a match when choice or jump is present that it is proceeded by {target= } with any number of characters after the =.
And also to match if continue or previous are present but only if they are proceeded by nothing.

so A = false, b = true, c = false, d = true, e = false, f = false, g = true, h = false, i = true, j = false, k = false and l = false,

with my regex above I get correct reading for everything bar j and l.

Can anyone please help?

Comment: you posted some answers that should be comments. I think you can still delete them and put them as comments. If I comment on the answers, you might not be able to delete them.

Comment: Actually, you can delete your answer regardless, I was confusing the procedure for deleting questions with the procedure for deleting answers.

Answer (score 1):

I think you want to replace

```
{target=(\w.*)}
```

with

```
{target=[^}]*}
```

This allows for any number of non-} characters after the "target=".

**EDIT:** Actually, could you please clarify your meaning? I gather from context that

"A = false, b = true, c = false, d = true, e = false, f = false, g = true, h = false, i = true, j = false, k = false and l = false"

are the *expected* values (rather than actual.. you should mention this explicitly for greater clarity). But based on your verbal description, l **(correction: a and f)** should be true, not false.

Also, I was going on a "fix one error at a time" basis. My regex still gives j true even though it should be false based on your verbal description. I'll make another edit shortly.

**EDIT 2:** I believe what you are after is

```
^({target=[^}]+}(choice|jump)|continue|previous)
```

**EDIT 3:** Sorry to edit so many times, but I should mention that taking the first `}` after the `=` is an assumption (albeit a common and often practical one). A more comprehensive test suite would indicate whether

```
{target=}}choice
```

should be a match.

Comment: doesnt this also match 0 occurences though?

Comment: @Shannow 0 is a number. If you want to disallow 0 you have to say so, as in "any nonzero number of characters".

Answer (score 0):

Similar to Mitch's answer, but:

```
{target=[^}]+}
```

This should match at least 1 non } character.